# global variable in controller laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

How can definition a global variable for use in all function controller

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $x;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->$x ='22';
    }            

    public function send_message()
    {
        echo $this->$x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Write `$this->x` rather than `$this->$x`

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $x;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->x ='22';
    }

    public function send_message()
    {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the value of $this->x?

Comment: @Vincent Yes you can. Like this: $this->x = 50;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make global variable in controller, the following code will work definitely:

```
private $x = 22;
    public function index()
    {
    print_r($this->x);
    die();
    }
```